# Regex pattern: number with quotation marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, validation

I have a regex which accepts decimal or number but i want to add quotation marks as well. so the pattern should accept

```
"123"
"123.12"
"123232.1222121"
```

This is the regex

```
/^\d*\.?\d*$/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optional double quotes at start & end:

```
/^(")?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\1$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gK4eS9/1)

**JS Demo**

```js
var regex = /^(")?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\1$/;

var result = document.getElementById('result');
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  var isValid = regex.test(this.value);

  // For showing the result on page: DEMO purpose only
  result.innerHTML = isValid ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid';
  result.className = isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
  this.className = isValid ? 'valid' : 'invalid';
}, false);
```

```css
input:valid, .valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid, .invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" />
<div id="result"></div>

<hr />
Using only HTML5 pattern attribute: <br />
<input pattern='(")?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\1' />
```

Comment: Use backreference `\1`. Current regex will also accept `"21` and `12"`.

Comment: not working      <textarea ng-model="exampleForm.inputAmount" ng-pattern="/^(")?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\1$/"  />

Comment: @OwaisAhmed: Check demo link to see it working. I don't know if `ng-pattern` supports back-reference but this works in JS

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle sample because the problem is (") this quotation marks

Comment: Try: `<textarea ng-model="exampleForm.inputAmount" ng-pattern='/^(")?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\1$/' />`

Comment: @anubhava Use `pattern` attribute. `ng-pattern` is only supported by AngularJS

Comment: Yes, it does support backreference.

Comment: @Tushar: Many thanks for adding the code snippet and demo. I'm not familiar with `AngularJS` but I believe this will definitely sort out OP's doubt.